# How to create a custom Desktop Background slideshow?

Tags: macos

I would like to have certain pictures as a **slideshow** on my Desktop background.
Currently, to do this, I am moving default pictures to a backup folder and putting my images there.
Isn't there an easy way to do this?

(I found an answer posted below)

Comment: Maybe others will disagree with me, but to me this feature is so obvious and commonly known about (or as you demonstrate easy to find) I'm not sure the question and answer have much added value for this site.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was puzzled at first, and when I found out the answer I just thought I would share it anyway.
But I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

### Add Folder to Desktop Background options

(self-answered)

I need create a Folder anywhere on my HDD, say (random example) 'Custom'.
I fill it with photos that I need in my background like a Slideshow. 
Now, I go to

```
System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Desktop
```

And on the panel on the left with Folders, there is a '+' sign on the bottom.
1. Click it,
2. Browse to folder,
3. Click Choose &
4. Check 'Change desktop background every __'